# i want to get two different values after check and uncheck of check box in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('#exp2').click(function(){
if ($(this).attr('checked',true)){          
    var getamt2 = $(this).val();
    var getamt4 = $('#amount_span').html(); alert(getamt4);
    /*var tot = getamt0+getamt1;
    $('#amount_span').html();*/
    $('#amount_span').html( parseInt(getamt4) + parseInt(getamt2)); 
}  
else{                   
        var getamt2 = $(this).val();
        var getamt4 = $('#amount_span').html(); alert('else');
       /*var tot = getamt0+getamt1;
       $('#amount_span').html();*/
       $('#amount_span').html( parseInt(getamt4) - parseInt(getamt2));

}
```

Comment: `if ($(this).attr('checked',true))` You are setting it, not getting it. This condition will always be truthly

Comment: in ths code i am not able to move in else condition.....so how can i do that....

Comment: Yes, that was the purpose of my previous comment. Show some effort trying to understand code you are obviously copying/pasting from somewhere else

Comment: okay sure i will do that.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if($(this).prop('checked')){
    your code..
}
```

and

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    your code..
}
```

like this:

```
$('#exp2').click(function(){
if ($(this).prop('checked')){  // <--- here is the edit         
    var getamt2 = $(this).val();
    var getamt4 = $('#amount_span').html(); alert(getamt4);
    /*var tot = getamt0+getamt1;
    $('#amount_span').html();*/
    $('#amount_span').html( parseInt(getamt4) + parseInt(getamt2)); 
}  
else{                   
        var getamt2 = $(this).val();
        var getamt4 = $('#amount_span').html(); alert('else');
       /*var tot = getamt0+getamt1;
       $('#amount_span').html();*/
       $('#amount_span').html( parseInt(getamt4) - parseInt(getamt2));
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, please set this as an answer if it answered your question.